# How to change screensaver user name and/or iterm2 top bar name on mac

Tags: macos, iterm, screensaver

I am new to macbook pro. A few weeks ago I bought used macbook pro. I tried to change user name and it looks somewhat well. But when I open my iterm2, something that I don't want is wroten(MBP085ui). My user name is bmy4415 and MBP085ui is not I want. And this also appears in my default screensaver. ScreenShots are below. How can I change MBP085ui to my custom name? And What is the official designation of that(for eaxmaple, It's username or It's unique name of device)

p.s I also changed my 'account name' and 'full name' from 'User & groups' tab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSQXS.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNZc8.png

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. You may improve your question at any time with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to properly change your account username, it is advisable to create a new account to ensure that absolutely nothing goes wrong and everything continues working as expected. However, it is very likely that someone may want to change their macOS user account name and/or home folder name, and Apple conveniently has a support article [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548).

I'm not sure which of these steps you may not have taken, so take a look at the support article and find out what you may have missed. As with any system modifications, I would suggest you to create a working backup with you can use in case anything goes wrong.